# Auto Layout - Do we have to specify a width and height for Command Buttons in Auto Layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I read that command buttons are intrinsic and that we should not specify the width and height otherwise there are chances that the text might be cut off. Is that correct ? f it is then why am I being asked to specify a width and a height in this case ? I have specified a `x` and `y`. Here is the picture

[image]

My question is why is the interface builder asking me to put in a width and height for the command button. How do I resolve this issue. I want the command button to change its width according to the content in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not being asked to specify the size. That message is telling you that the current size is not the intrinsic size determined by that title. Just click on the yellow triangle then on "fix misplacement" in the window that comes up.

Comment: So in order to resolve that issue , if I select "Update Constraints" will I be limiting myself to a fixed size then ? Since updating a constraint I believe will put in a width and height automatically. Will doing that make a control non-intrinsic ?

Comment: @MistyD, don't select "Update Constraints", do as I said in my answer or select "Update Frames".

Comment: If I do that then the width of the button decreases. I want to add some space after the text. I do not want the border of the button close to the text inside the button. is there a way to accomplish that ?

Comment: @MistyD You can do that with the contentEdgeInsets
  property. For example,  `button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 20)` will give you 20 points of padding on the left and right sides, but none extra on the top or bottom.